# Saying 'he went' with itta

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

彼はいった

Is there a better more fluent way to say 'he went'?

Comment: If you mean 'he left', then maybe 立ち去った?

Comment: Can you add some context? In what situation do you want to use it?

Answer (score 1):

> 彼はいった
>
> Is there a better more fluent way to say 'he went'?

Yes, there are.

彼{かれ}は行{い}った is simply a direct translation of "He went." It could be used as part of a dry narrative, but we don't usually say things this way to talk to someone.

If it's part of a conversation, it could be like
彼は行ったよ [for casual talk]
彼は行きましたよ [standard language to talk to people]
○○さんは行かれました（よ） [polite language]

If it's from a novel, it could be like
彼は行った。[dry and concise]
彼は行きました。[more accessible / this is the standard to write to people]
彼は行ったのであった。[dry and explanatory tone]

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto karlalou's answer, you can use different verbs depending on your context. Generally you can use 行った for 'went' but consider the following as well:

> 彼は[出かけた/出かけました]。
>  He went (out from home).
>
> 彼はXXに[向かった/向かいました]。
>  He went (towards XX).

行った works here too, but 向かった gives the sense of going towards a very specific place.